# How can I intercept Ajax responses in ExtJs?

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, interceptor, extjs5

I'm working on a project with [extjs](/questions/tagged/extjs) and I need to intercept all `ajax` responses before they are handled by their respective caller code.

In [axios](/questions/tagged/axios), for example, I can do:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
    function (response) {
        // handle response
        return response;
    }, function (error) {

});
```

How can I do that in `extjs` ? The docs for [Ext.Ajax](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.4/api/Ext.Ajax.html#event-beforerequest) seem to provide only  `events` for requests.

---

*I'd prefer not installing any additional plug-in / dependency*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs I have linked show the event `requestcomplete`, which is fired when a `response` comes back from the server.

I wrongly assumed it was fired right after the request was sent.

---

So, listening to `requestcomplete` is the right way to go.

You can catch successful and unsuccessful responses with the following code:

```
Ext.Ajax.on('requestcomplete', function ( conn, response, options ) {

});

Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', function ( conn, response, options ) {

});
```